# Simplification of determinant of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

For the following 4x4  matrix $M$,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & -b & 0 & d\\ 
-b & a & -d & 0\\ 
0 & -d & -a & -b \\ 
d & 0 & -b & -a \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
it can be expressed in 2x2 block matrix form so that,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\ 
-B & D
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Using the well known formula,
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\ 
C & D
\end{pmatrix}=\det(A-BD^{-1}C)\det(D)
\end{equation}
The determinant of of $M$ can be 
\begin{equation}
 \begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\ 
-B & D
\end{pmatrix}=\det(A+BD^{-1}B)\det(D)
\end{equation}
Can it be simplified further?